# Cannot sync Google Drive between MacBook and iPhone app

Tags: data-synchronization, google-apps, google-sync

On my iPhone I installed GoogleDrive 'Drive' app.

On my MacBook I installed `Backup and sync from Google.app`, which has created a `~/google-drive/` folder.

I have set the account to `my@gmail.com` and put some files and folders in it.

On my iPhone app I also set the account to `my@gmail.com`. I can see some of the older folders. These appear to match that on my MacBook, although the contained files are out of date. I can also see a file dated about a week ago which I have since deleted on my MacBook.

Files I have added/removed within the last 24 hours on my MacBook simply don't register on the iPhone.

It seems clear that the devices are out of sync. But they're both connected to my apartment's Wi-Fi.

I can't find any `sync` button / menuitem.

This is very frustrating.

What is going on? I was hoping that Google Drive would be my solution for distributed storage.

EDIT:  The Google Drive web-app (Chrome -> drive.google.com/drive/u/1/my-drive) *does* sync ok with my macbook. Which suggests an issue with the iPhone `Drive` app, maybe?

Comment: Does it eventually sync on your iPhone if you leave the Drive app open, the screen on, and the iPhone awake?  Do you have background app refresh turned on for Drive?

Answer (score 1):

Just clicking on `Search drive` in the app was sufficient to jiggle something loose and sync `cloud -> iphone`.

I noticed one glitch. The iPhone Drive app was failing to display `bar.txt` which *IS* on cloud (I added it yesterday), but instead was still displaying a `foo.pdf` file that longer exists on the cloud (which was showing up even before I asked the question), and bizarrely clicking on `foo.pdf` actually shows the contents of `bar.txt`.

Reinstalling the Drive App resolves this.

EDIT: I can recreate the problem as follows:
 - On my MacBook I copy X.txt to ~/google-drive
 - Observe that the cloud icon in the tray does `sync` animation
 - Observe that X.txt does not appear on Drive app
 - Drive App -> `Search drive` for X.txt
 - Now it is visible